# Flutter - How to only update/rebuild the child widget and not parent?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following code where 'Snag' is the parent widget and 'Category Display' is the child widget. When I press 'CATEGORY' button the display updates but the entire 'SNAG' is also rebuild as a result I get a flicker on the screen.

Please see attached: [image]

What is it that I am doing wrong here please?

My code is as follows:

```
class Snags extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnagsState createState() => _SnagsState();
}

class _SnagsState extends State<Snags> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController _locationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _conditionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _recommendationController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _assetController = TextEditingController();

  bool _newSnag = false;
  bool _busy = false;
  bool loaded = false;

  late Snag? _snag;

  late InfoHelper _info;
  late StatusCodes _statusCodes;

  late String _imagePath;
  late String _status;
  late String _siteID;
  double maxImageSize = 700;

  _getSnagObject() async {
    if (loaded) return;
    _info = ModalRoute
        .of(context)!
        .settings
        .arguments as InfoHelper;
    _siteID = _info.siteID; // Never NULL
    _newSnag = _info.problemUID == null ? true : false;
    if (!_newSnag) {
      _snag = await MyDatabase.db.getSingleSnag(_info.problemUID!);
    }
    _statusCodes = await Provider.of<CP>(context,listen: false).getStatusCodes();
    _imagePath = _newSnag ? '' : _snag!.imagePath;
    _status = _newSnag ? '1' : _snag!.Status;
    _locationController.text = _newSnag ? '' : _snag!.location;
    _conditionController.text = _newSnag ? '' : _snag!.condition;
    _recommendationController.text = _newSnag ? '' : _snag!.recommendation;
    _assetController.text = _newSnag ? '' : _snag!.asset;
    loaded = true;
  }

  deleteImage() async {
    if (await File(_imagePath).exists()) await File(_imagePath).delete();
    setState(() => _imagePath = '');
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  annotatePicture() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/imageMarkup', arguments: _imagePath).then((value) {
      if (value != null)
        setState(() {
          _imagePath = value as String;
        });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }

  void _openGallery() async {
    XFile? picture = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxHeight: maxImageSize,
      maxWidth: maxImageSize,
    );
    await savePicture(picture);
  }

  void _openCamera() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    XFile? picture = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: maxImageSize,
      maxWidth: maxImageSize,
    );
    await savePicture(picture);
  }

  Future optionsDialogBoxWithDELorEDIT(BuildContext context1,
      VoidCallback callBackDelete, VoidCallback? callBackEdit) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context1,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: new Text('Delete picture'),
                    onTap: callBackDelete,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 26.0,),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: new Text('Annotate picture'),
                    onTap: callBackEdit,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Future<void> _optionsDialogBox() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: new SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: new Text('Take a picture'),
                    onTap: () => _openCamera(),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    child: new Text('Select from gallery'),
                    onTap: () => _openGallery(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  savePicture(XFile? picture) async {
    if (picture != null) {
      try {
        final String path = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
        final String completePath = p.join(path, '${DateTime.now().toIso8601String() + ".png"}');
        await picture.saveTo(completePath);
        setState(() => _imagePath = completePath);
        if (kDebugMode) print('IMAGE SAVED TO: $_imagePath');
      } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) print(e);
        MyFirebaseServices.recordNonFatalError(message: 'Could not save image. Error = $e');
      }
      // TRY SAVE IT IN EXTERNAL STORAGE AS WELL
      try {
        if ((await Provider.of<CP>(context, listen: false).getProfile())!.saveExternally) {
          final String path = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!.path;
          final String completePath = p.join(path, '${DateTime.now().toIso8601String() + ".png"}');
          await picture.saveTo(completePath);
        }
      } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) print(e);
        MyFirebaseServices.recordNonFatalError(message: 'Could not save image. Error = $e');
      }
    }
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getSnagObject(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print (snapshot.stackTrace);
          } else {
            MyFirebaseServices.logMessage(message: 'Snag - snapshot error ${snapshot.error}');
          }
          return ErrorStatus(message: 'Error: Please go back and try again!');
        }
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            flexibleSpace: TitleBarBackground(),
            title: Text('SNAG', style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary)),
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            elevation: 1.0,
            leading: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async =>
                  _imagePath.isEmpty
                      ? await _optionsDialogBox()
                      : await optionsDialogBoxWithDELorEDIT(context, deleteImage, annotatePicture),
                  child: MainImage(
                    imagePath: _imagePath,
                  ),
                ),
                SafeArea(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _locationController,
                                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9-,. ]'))],
                                maxLines: 1,
                                maxLength: 30,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Location',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.add_location,
                                      size: 35.0,
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .primary,
                                    )),
                                validator: (value) =>
                                value == null || value.isEmpty
                                    ? '*REQUIRED*'
                                    : null,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _assetController,
                                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9-,. ]'))],
                                maxLines: 1,
                                maxLength: 40,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Asset',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.web_asset,
                                      size: 35.0,
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .primary,
                                    )),
                                validator: (value) =>
                                value == null || value.isEmpty
                                    ? '*REQUIRED*'
                                    : null,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _conditionController,
                                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9-,. ]'))],
                                maxLines: 1,
                                maxLength: 50,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Condition',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.star,
                                      size: 35.0,
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .primary,
                                    )),
                                validator: (value) =>
                                value == null || value.isEmpty
                                    ? '*REQUIRED*'
                                    : null,
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                controller: _recommendationController,
                                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9-,. ]'))],
                                maxLines: 4,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Description',
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.description,
                                      size: 35.0,
                                      color: Theme
                                          .of(context)
                                          .colorScheme
                                          .primary,
                                    )),
                                validator: (value) =>
                                value == null || value.isEmpty
                                    ? '*REQUIRED*'
                                    : null,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        CategoryDisplay(currentSelection:currentSelection(_status), statusCodes: _statusCodes, callBackFunction: changeSelection,),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20.0,
                        ),
                        SaveButton(
                          label: 'SAVE',
                          busy: _busy,
                          callBackfunction: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              _formKey.currentState!.save();
                              if (!_busy) {
                                setState(() => _busy = true);
                                if (_newSnag) {
                                  var uid = Uuid();
                                  Snag snag = Snag(
                                    id: uid.v4(),
                                    siteID: _siteID,
                                    imagePath: _imagePath,
                                    Status: _status,
                                    recommendation: _recommendationController.text,
                                    condition: _conditionController.text,
                                    asset: _assetController.text,
                                    location: _locationController.text,
                                  );
                                  await MyDatabase.db.insertSnag(snag);
                                  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 250));
                                  Navigator.pop(context, snag);
                                } else {
                                  Snag snag = Snag(
                                    id: _snag!.id,
                                    siteID: _snag!.siteID,
                                    imagePath: _imagePath,
                                    Status: _status,
                                    recommendation: _recommendationController.text,
                                    condition: _conditionController.text,
                                    asset: _assetController.text,
                                    location: _locationController.text,
                                  );
                                  await MyDatabase.db.updateSnag(snag);
                                  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 250));
                                  Navigator.pop(context, snag);
                                }
                                setState(() => _busy = false);
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      return BusyStatus(message: 'Loading...');
    },
    );
  }

  changeSelection(String selection){
    setState(() {
      _status = selection;
    });
  }
  currentSelection(String status){
    //If it is String then send INT
    int? s = int.tryParse(status);
    if (s!=null) return s;
    // If it is old String text then send correct INT conversion
    if (status == 'OK') status = "1";
    if (status == 'OBS') status = "2";
    if (status == 'CAT3') status = "3";
    if (status == 'CAT2') status = "4";
    if (status == 'CAT1') status = "5";
    print (status);
    return int.parse(status);
  }
}




class CategoryDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryDisplay({required this.callBackFunction, required this.currentSelection, required this.statusCodes, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Function callBackFunction;
  final int currentSelection;
  final StatusCodes statusCodes;


  String _getDescription(int status) {
    if (status == 1) return statusCodes.aDes;
    if (status == 2) return statusCodes.bDes;
    if (status == 3) return statusCodes.cDes;
    if (status == 4) return statusCodes.dDes;
    if (status == 5) return statusCodes.eDes;
    return ('SELECT STATUS');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('CATEGORY', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => callBackFunction("1"),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width / 6,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentSelection == 1
                      ? Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .primary
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .primary,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    statusCodes.a,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentSelection == 1
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .primary),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => callBackFunction("2"),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width / 6,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentSelection == 2
                      ? Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .primary
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .primary,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    statusCodes.b,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentSelection == 2
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .primary),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => callBackFunction("3"),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width / 6,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentSelection == 3
                      ? Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .primary
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .primary,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    statusCodes.c,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentSelection == 3
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .primary),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => callBackFunction("4"),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width / 6,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentSelection == 4
                      ? Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .primary
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .primary,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    statusCodes.d,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentSelection == 4
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .primary),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => callBackFunction("5"),
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                width: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .width / 6,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: currentSelection == 5
                      ? Theme
                      .of(context)
                      .colorScheme
                      .primary
                      : Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .primary,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                    width: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    statusCodes.e,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: currentSelection == 5
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .colorScheme
                            .primary),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 4,),
        Center(
            child: Text(
              _getDescription(currentSelection),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your parent, to avoid that change `changeSelection` to this:

```
changeSelection(String selection){
   _status = selection;
}
```

then change your `CategoryDisplay` to `StatefulWidget` and define new `_status` inside `CategoryDisplay` and after that change `onTap` to this:

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
     setState(() {
      _status = 1;
     });
     callBackFunction("1"),
   }
```

repeat this for all your `onTap`.

Comment: Thanks! But this raises a question in my mind. I always thought whatever is in the setState will trigger the rebuild of the associated widget etc, NOT the rebuild of the entire class which holds setState?

Comment: when you call setState it rebuilds entire class and change every value that differ from previous state. for example here you put `_status = 1;` out of setState but still update its value.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself properly. What I mean is, if '_status' is associated with one child widget (and goes in as input), when parent class called set state and changes _status, should it not be the case that only child widget is updated as that _status is not used anywhere in the parent class?

Comment: no it updates the parent state, read about [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) here.

Comment: Sorry but not fully convinced/understand this. I just created a fresh flutter App, if you see the demo app, pressing on FAB, updates counter which updates the text on the screen, setState does not redraw the entire screen, just where counter variable is used! It does not redraw the parent, just the children where state of the stateful object (i.e. counter) is linked. Should it not be the same with my code with '_status'?

Comment: if you put print in that build method you will see it rebuild the parent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249048/discussion-between-damandroid-and-eamirho3ein).